# $_GET['value'] wont work?

Tags: php, function, get

I'm trying to make a small browser game, but I cant get a value from the $_GET[] value out of the URL. Can anyone confirm I'm doing the right things, or just going all rampage PHP stuff?

```
    // General settings
    $site = "http://localhost/index.php";
    $buildfood0 = "dSDF3HJKhbv432dsfs";
    // Food forms
    $form_food0 = "<img src='./images/game/b7_.png' /><a class='button' href='$site?code=$buildfood0'>Build</a>";

    if($lvl_food == 0){
        if($_GET['code']) {
            $codefood = $_GET['code'];
                if($codefood0 == $buildfood0){
                    require("./connect.php");   
                    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lvl_farm='1' WHERE username='$username'");                            
                    mysql_close();
                }
                else
                    null;       
            }           
        }       
    else if($lvl_food == 1){
        echo "<img src='./images/game/b7.png' />";
    }
```

Comment: You're mixing up `$codefood` and `$codefood0`. Get an IDE that can highlight trivial problems like that.

Comment: What is `$codefood0` when you have `codefood`?

Comment: Agree with DCoder, but you should also try naming your variables better

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if($lvl_food == 0){
    if($_GET['code']) {
        $codefood = $_GET['code'];
            if($codefood0 == $buildfood0){
------------------------^ // Wrong. Remove the 0
```

Make it as:

```
if($lvl_food == 0){
    if($_GET['code']) {
        $codefood = $_GET['code'];
            if($codefood == $buildfood0){
```

Comment: Still wont work, it's because I tried everything, and forgot that. Anyhow, it wont work.

Comment: Show the full code, explain what you wanted to do.

Comment: In index.php I wanted to make the query refresh automaticly to update the resources (wood, food, etc.) This is the code for that. 

<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
 
   <script type="text/javascript">
    refreshdiv();
   </script>
   
   <div id="refreshContent"><p><center><img src='./images/loading.gif' /></p><p><b>Loading content - Please wait</b></center></div></center> 

After that, I want to display houses, etc, with the code I initially posted.

Comment: Bleh it wont show the code right, its 3 lines, hope you understand. Anyway, in that window, it calls 'content.php', which is autorefreshed every second so it shows the right data. That also holds the initial code, so it updates correctly.